# ViewPager2 with TabLayout swipes to next position on Tab tapped

Tags: android-viewpager2

I prepared on github (https://github.com/SertanAcubens/ViewPagertest) sample app to illustrate problem I encountered while migrating to ViewPager2. Shortly, one of fragments in ViewPager is built from CardViews (with RecyclerView inside) which are added in fragment's onViewCreated method. When Tab Three is tapped ViewPager2 swipes immediately to next position. I would appreciate any help on that issue.
Seems like this bug affects at least devices with Android 9. On some devices with Android 11 works OK.

Comment: is this happening to you always? because I tried your code and it's not happening to me.

Comment: Always, but only after starting app. And you need to tap tab three as first choice. When you select other tab or swipe ViewPager than everything works fine.

Comment: Works OK on LG Velvet. Strange behaviour occurs on Emulator and Galaxy J3. Has android version anything to do with it?